# Database table Column filtered autocomplete input data according to selected field

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

I want to show filtered data as an autocomplete input according the selected by userId in an input field. I have userId, data fields in database table. In the page, when user enters a data to an input field I want to show only this user's data fields as an autocomplete field. How can I do this. I hope I clarified the problem.

The following code works without filtering:
In the code parameter table is used. But I want to use UserSearchedWord table which consist of userid and data fields.

```
 <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeFile="AutoCompleteParameterTextBox.ascx.cs"       Inherits="AutoCompleteParameterTextBox" %> 
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function ($) {
    try {
        if ($('script[src="/Assets/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"]').length == 0) {
            var s = document.createElement("script");
            s.type = "text/javascript";
            s.src = "/Assets/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js";
            $("body").append(s);
        }
        if ($('link[href="/Assets/css/jquery-ui.min.css"]').length == 0) {
            $("head").append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Assets/css/jquery-ui.min.css" 
 type="text/css" />');
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
    }
});

function CallServer() {
    <%=PostBackScript%>
}

function stripNonAlphaNumeric(string) {
    var r = string.toLowerCase();
    r = r.replace(new RegExp("[^A-z0-9şŞıİçÇöÖüÜĞğ.,-/() ]", 'g'), "");
    return r;
}

var initAutoComplete
    = (function () {
        $(function () {
            $("#<%=txt.ClientID%>").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    var hiddenInputValueName = $("#<%=hdnRadioId.ClientID %>").val();
                    if (hiddenInputValueName) {
                        var inputValue = $('input[name$="' + hiddenInputValueName + 
     '"]:checked').val();
                        if (inputValue) request.term = inputValue + '-' + request.term;
                        else {
                            $("#<%=txt.ClientID%>").val('');
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                    var host = "";

                    if (window.location.hostname == "localhost") {
                        host = '<%=GetBaseUrl()%>';
                    }
                    else {
                        host = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
                    }
                    var parametertable = '<%=ParameterTable%>';

                    if ((hiddenInputValueName && request.term.substr(2).trim() === '') || 
    (!hiddenInputValueName && request.term.trim() === '')) response(null);
                    else {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: host + "/api/parameterapi/" + parametertable + "/" +

    stripNonAlphaNumeric(request.term),
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (data) {
                                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                    return {
                                        label: item.Aciklama,
                                        value: item.KayitNo
                                    }
                                }));
                            }
                        });
                    }
                },
                autoFill: true,
                minLength: 3,
                delay: 300,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#<%=txt.ClientID %>").val(ui.item.label);
                    $("#<%=hdn.ClientID %>").val(ui.item.value.toString());
                    CallServer();
                    return false;
                },
                focus: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#<%=txt.ClientID %>").val(ui.item.label);
                    return false;
                },
                change: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#<%=hdn.ClientID %>").val(ui.item ? ui.item.value : "");
                },
                open: function () {
                    $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
                },
                close: function () {
                    $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            }).blur(function () {
                //$(this).autocomplete("close");
            }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                var newText = String(item.label).replace(
                    new RegExp(this.term, "gi"),
                    "<span class='ui-state-highlight'>$&</span>");

                return $("<li></li>")
                    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                    .append("<a>" + newText + "</a>")
                    .appendTo(ul);
            };
        });
    });

    if (undefined === window.Sys) {
        initAutoComplete();
    }
    else {
          Sys.Application.add_load(function (s, e) {
            initAutoComplete();
        });
       }
  </script>
  <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt" CssClass="input-xlarge"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblRequired" CssClass="REQUIRED" Text="*" Visible="false" />
  <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdn" />
  <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnParameterTable" />
  <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnRadioId" />
  <span><small>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl">Üç Harf Giriniz.</asp:Label></small></span>
```

Comment: you don't show your server side method, but in your web method (end point) that you are calling, simple add the user id as part of the SQL query where criteria for filtering the results back to the client side. So, edit your question, and post the web method (server side code) you are using here. it should be a simple matter to add the user id to that existing query and server side code.